# How to find all stored procedures and table from a single stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on a database which has does a lot of stored procedures and tables.

One brute force way to know all the stored procedures and tables called by a single stored procedure is by scanning and reading through the code. However, it takes a lot of time.

what is the query to find out all the stored procedures and tables that are called by a main stored procedure?

Comment: To make the question clearer with example. Let's say stored procedure 1 (SP) calls SP2 and table 2, and SP2 calls SP3 and table 3. Could i run a query including SP1 to list SP2, table 2, SP3 and table 3?

Answer (score 2):

You can query [sys.objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) and [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx) tables like this:

```
SELECT sys.objects.name, sys.objects.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies 
INNER JOIN sys.objects ON(referenced_id = object_id)
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID('<Your stored procedure name here>')
```

Don't forget to replace `<Your stored procedure name here>` with the actual name of the stored procedure.

**Update:**
A stored procedure called from another stored procedure will still have a row in `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`, but will have a null value in the `referenced_id` column. you can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @StoredProcedureName sysname = '<Your stored procedure name here>'

SELECT sys.objects.name, sys.objects.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies 
INNER JOIN sys.objects ON(referenced_id = object_id)
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(@StoredProcedureName)

UNION ALL

SELECT procedures.name , 'Stored Procedure' As type_desc
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies 
INNER JOIN sys.procedures ON(referenced_entity_name = sys.procedures.name)
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(@StoredProcedureName)
AND referenced_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for the query, i found all the tables called, including the joined tables, within the stored procedures using this solution. However, it does not detect "exec <sub stored procedures> portion" called by the main <stored procedure>. Is there a way to include stored procedures called?